# Create an array of n elements

Tags: perl

I'm looking for the Perlish way to create an array of n elements where each element is 0.

This is the best I could come up with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use feature qw<say>;

print "Enter length of array: ";
chomp(my $len = <STDIN>);

my @arr = split // => "0" x $len;

say "@arr  ", scalar(@arr);
```

I also look at List::Util's reduce but it wasn't as compact as the above snippet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perl's arrays expand as necessary.  You don't have to create them up front.  Why do you want to create an array of a defined length?

The way to do what you're asking is:

```
my @a = (0) x $n;
```

where `$n` is the number of elements, but again, it might not be appropriate.  Tell us more about what the problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: another way: `my @a = map { 0 } 1..$n;`

Answer (score -1):

Less elegant way to fill an array with some value (for demonstration purpose only)

```
my $n = 8;
my @array;

$array[$n] = 0 while $n--;
```

Comment: This is not perlish way